# Expression width 32 does not match width 1 of logic gate array port 1

Tags: verilog

I have two questions.

1. No output
2. Expression width 32 does not match width 1 of logic gate array port 1.

When I write `and( OutAnd, a, b);`, it shows an error.

```
Expression width 32 does not match width 1 of logic gate array port 1.
```

How can I fix it?

By the way. I forbid to use `&` operator, Procedure Assignment, and always block.

Here's my code:

ALU.v

```
module ALU( 
  input [5:0] Signal, 
  input [31:0] a, b,
  output reg[31:0] Output
  );
  
  wire[31:0] OutAnd;
  
  and( OutAnd, a, b); // AND  <-- error
  AluMux alumax0( .Signal(Signal), .in_And( OutAnd ) ); // AND
endmodule
```

AluMax.v

```
module AluMux(
  input [5:0] Signal,
  input [31:0] in_And, in_Or,
  output reg[31:0] Output
  );
  
  parameter AND = 6'd36;
  
  always @ ( * )
  begin
    case ( Signal )
        AND : Output = in_And;
         default : Output = 32'd11;
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the `and` gate defined to be 1 bit and you want to put 32 bits in it which may cause an error or a warning to solve this you have 2 way either instantiate 32 and gates with the following syntax

```
and u1 (OutAnd[0], a[0], b[0]);
and u1 (OutAnd[1], a[1], b[1]);
and u1 (OutAnd[2], a[2], b[2]);
.
.
.
and u1 (OutAnd[31], a[31], b[31]);
```

or use a generate statement here is a sample code

```
genvar i;

generate 

for(i = 0;i < 32;i = i + 1) begin 

and u1(OutAnd[i], a[i], b[i]);


end

endgenerate
```